# use of undefined 'Player' and 'player' uses undefined 'Player' errors

Tags: c++, class

```
class Skeleton {
public:
    void attack(Player player) {
        if (canAttackSkeleton()) {
            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - _attackDamage); //C2027 and C2228 for setHealth() and getHealth()
            return;
        }
    }
    void getAttacked(Player player) {
        _health -= player.getAttackDamage(); //C2027 and C2228 for getAttackDamage()
    }


private:
    float _attackDamage = 100.0f;
};

class Player{
public:
    void attack(Skeleton skeleton) {
        if (canAttackPlayer()) {
            skeleton.setHealth(skeleton.getHealth() - _attackDamage);
            return;
        }
    }
    void getAttacked(Skeleton skeleton) {
        _health -= skeleton.getAttackDamage();
    }


private:
    float _attackDamage = 100.0f;
};
```

This is my code plus the main function

Basically I get "`use of undefined 'Player'`" with the error code `C2027`. Also, for `.setHealth`, `.getHealth` and `.getAttackDamage`, I get the error "`must have class/struct/union`" with the error code `C2228`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why pass by value everywhere?

Comment: you can use either `forward declaration` or `templates` to achieve your task

Comment: do you know a bit about templates?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I know very little about c++ since I have been only learning about this in school for two years and they teach us easy stuff which I already knew from other languages. The answer is I don't know about templates or anything besides basic programming in c++

Comment: @Raindrop7 this is my code as of yet http://pastebin.com/GEkD5DyF

Comment: can explain what is this then: `uniform_real_distribution<float> attackChance(0.0f, 1.0f);`?

Comment: I saw that in a tutorial. I previously wanted the attack to happen 30% of the time and I used that to generate a random number between 0.0f and 1.0f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined means the compiler cannot find the definition of Player. If you switch the order then you will get an error for undefined Skeleton. You should consider have a Character Class.

```
#include<iostream>
class Character {
public:
    Character() : health(100), attackDamage(10) {}
    virtual void attack(Character& other) {
        other.getAttacked(*this);
    }
    virtual void getAttacked(Character& other) {
        this->health -= other.getAttackDamage();
    }
    virtual int getHealth() const { return health; }
    virtual void setHealth(int Health) { health = Health; }
    virtual int getAttackDamage() const { return attackDamage; }
    virtual void setAttackDamage(int AttackDamage) { attackDamage = AttackDamage; }

protected:
    int health;
    int attackDamage;
};

class Player : public Character {

};

class Skeleton : public Character {

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Player player;
    Skeleton skeleton;
    std::cout << "Before attack...\n\nPlayer Health: " << player.getHealth() << std::endl << "Skeleton Health: " << skeleton.getHealth() << std::endl;

    player.attack(skeleton);
    std::cout << "After attack...\n\nPlayer Health: " << player.getHealth() << std::endl << "Skeleton Health: " << skeleton.getHealth() << std::endl;

    player.setAttackDamage(50);
    std::cout << "Updated player attack to 50" << std::endl;
    player.attack(skeleton);

    std::cout << "After second attack with 50 attack damage...\n\nPlayer Health: " << player.getHealth() << std::endl << "Skeleton Health: " << skeleton.getHealth() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what should I do? 
I tried putting them in different files but it gives me the same errors.

Comment: You can leave then in the compilation file (where the main function is). Just put the code before the beginning of the main function. Since Skeleton is a Character and Player is a Character you can define void attack(const Character& other) , then pass Skeleton or Player or any other class that is derived from Character to the attack method.

Comment: and how do I do this for other.getHealth(), setHealth() and getAttackDamage()?

Comment: @TeoVecerdi: You decide whether the functions are part of the common `Character` base class or are specific to a single character subtype.  They look generic (all characters probably have health and damage ratings); they should probably be in the base class.  You need to specify them in some appropriate class before you can call them.  You'll also need to think what you're going to do when you get Zombies as well as Skeletons in your game.

Comment: @Raindrop7: you're very adamant this is wholly incorrect — can you explain why?  A common base class for characters seems likely to be a good way to go.

Comment: @TeoVecerdi the code above is not the entire solution to your problem. I am suggesting you use a concept known as class inheritance. The usefulness of inheritance is explained by Jonathan Leffler's comment above.

Comment: @JustinLye 's answer kinda fixed the errors. I had to add <code>float _health;</code> and </code>float _attackDamage;</code> as private variables in class Character and then in Player and Skeleton assigned values to them but when running they're <code>-1.07374e+08</code>. What should I do?

Comment: @Raindrop7 the answer is you cannot use something that has not been defined, but that doesn't seem very helpful to someone learning what a class is and how a class can be used.

Comment: @JustinLye and if I want different health or attackDamage for Skeleton and Player what should I do?

Comment: @TeoVecerdi I updated the post. I added a method setAttackDamage to the Character class, then used that method in the main function in the second attack. I would recommend you search youtube for a c++ class tutorial series, there are a variety of good ones. Also, keep in mind the code above does not comply with "best practices".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to separate class definition/declaration from the implementation part. Together with a forward declaration (or a simple `class`-token before a class type that has not been defined up to that point) this should help.

Note that the code you provided is not complete (e.g. it lacks method `canAttackSkeleton` and some more). Hence, this fragment does not compile. Compiler errors mentioned in your OP, however, should be solved then.

Concerning the code itself, there seems to be some room for improvements / refactoring (e.g. using call by reference instead of call by value as suggested by comments). However, this has actually not been your question, so I don't add any more comments here.

The code would look then as follows:

```cpp
// header file (.h):
class Skeleton {
public:
    void attack(class Player player);
    void getAttacked(class Player player);

private:
    float _attackDamage = 100.0f;
};

class Player {
public:
    void attack(Skeleton skeleton);
    void getAttacked(Skeleton skeleton);

private:
    float _attackDamage = 100.0f;
};

// implementation file (.cpp):
void Skeleton::attack(Player player) {
    if (canAttackSkeleton()) {
        player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - _attackDamage); //C2027 and C2228 for setHealth() and getHealth()
        return;
    }
}

void Skeleton::getAttacked(Player player) {
    _health -= player.getAttackDamage(); //C2027 and C2228 for getAttackDamage()
}

void Player::attack(Skeleton skeleton) {
    if (canAttackPlayer()) {
        skeleton.setHealth(skeleton.getHealth() - _attackDamage);
        return;
    }
}

void Player::getAttacked(Skeleton skeleton) {
    _health -= skeleton.getAttackDamage();
}
```